# Driver, 32-bit in arm.

Tags: c++, arm, gpib

I'm do a project to control a gpib-usb converter from national instruments. I will run the app on raspberry pi 2 using a windows 10 iot core. On this configuration, is only possible to do a universal app to run. That's what i do.

The library is in c/c++, so comes with a gpib-32.obj. 
Here is the trouble, when i compile my universal app on raspberry pi, give me the error **Error LNK1112 module machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'ARM'**.

There is somehow i can do this app run? If i delete this file, the library don't work.

regards, vitor.

Answer (score 2):

Your choices are to either recompile the library from the source code using the gcc that's on the raspberry pi or use C#.

When using the raspberry pi, I use the debian (raspbian) linux build. I researched the windows 10 for raspberry pi and found it to be a cruel joke intended to sabotage the raspberry pi project.

I have good luck running mono on the raspberry pi to get c# programs running without recompiling the program for the raspberry pi.

I hope this guides you in the right direction.

Comment: in c#, wont give the same error? I already compile a project in c#, which one i just add a button and the .obj file. But i thought that supposed to happen because, i don't using the library and just compile .obj, since c# is a managed language. 

I already try linux, but the driver of this hardware is very strange.